# How do I find the volume of ocean between any two layers of ocean depth?

Tags: ocean, bathymetry

I'm interested in this problem because I'm interested in obtaining a rough estimate of the average temperature increase of the sea given a net radiative forcing of 0.6 W/m^2.

But in order to obtain an estimate, I need to know the volume of the ocean between 0-2000m. I'm also interested in knowing the volume of the ocean between any other two arbitrary layers of the ocean (0-1000m, 1000-2000m, 0-4000m, etc..)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for volume? Volume = height x width x depth.  If you are curious about a particular ocean... you could look up the surface area of the ocean and multiply it times the depth.

Comment: Yes. Thing is, bathymetry matters, making width hard to calculate.

Comment: Ah so it sounds like you want a computer program like ArcGIS that can load bathymetry and do 3-D computations.

Answer (score 7):

You can find gridded topography and bathymetry data, freely accessible, on the website of the NOAA. For instance you have the ETOPO1 dataset [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html).

Once you downloaded it you can work it out with your favourite GIS software or GIS-supporting programming language.

The equations to calculate the volume based on the gridded cells is given on [this page](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/etopo1_ocean_volumes.html) from the NGDC website.

> Volume Calculation
>
> Volumes were calculated for each ocean grid cell in ETOPO1 using
>   Equation 1 to determine cell area, and Equation 2 to determine cell
>   volume. Cell areas and volumes were then summed over each ocean or
>   marginal sea.
>
> Equation 1: $dA = \frac{a^2\cdot cos(ø)\cdot (1-e^2)\cdot dø\cdot dl}{(1-e^2 \cdot sin^2ø)^2}$
>   Equation 2: $dV = dA \cdot depth$
>
> where:
>   Latitude (ø)  = latitude of cell's center (in radians)
>   Unit of Latitude (dø) = 1 arc-minute ($2.908882 \cdot 10^{-4}$ radians)
>   Unit of Longitude (dl)    = 1 arc-minute ($2.908882 \cdot 10^{-4}$ radians)
>
> The WGS84 spheroid was used for values of Earth's radius and
>   eccentricity:
>   Equatorial radius (a) = 6378.137 km
>   Eccentricity (e)  = 0.08181919